# Recursive XSL Selection

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<nodes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <element>Content1</element>
    <element>Content2</element>
    <element>Content3</element>
    <parent>
        <element>Content4</element>
        <element>Content5</element>
            <parent>
                <element>Content6</element>
                    <parent>
                        <element>Content7</element>
                        <element>Content8</element>
                    </parent>
                <element>Content9</element>
            </parent>
        <element>Content10</element>
        <element>Content11</element>
    </parent>
    <element>Content12</element>
    <parent>
        <element>Content13</element>
        <element>Content14</element>
    </parent>
    <element>Content15</element>
</nodes>
```

I want to select all nodes called elements, also if they are inside of parent and i want to know how many parent elements they have so I can display this html structure in html like this:

```
<pre>
Content1
Content2
Content3
    Content4
    Content5
        Content6
            Content7
            Content8
        Content9
    Content10
    Content11
Content12
    Content13
    Content14
Content15
</pre>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If your intention is to display the hierarchy in HTML, why don't you use nested lists to do so - see an example here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GgbD2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code for doing this in XSL is:

```
<pre>
  <xsl:for-each select="//element">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::parent">
        <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>
</pre>
```

Explanation:

- <pre> is html tag to display code
- //element selects every node called element no matter where it is in the hierarchy. Be carefull with big XML documents.
- select="ancestor::parent" selects all parent nodes with the node name "parent"
- <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text> inserts the desired tab. xsl:text tag is necessary because XSL considers: ASCII Tab: &#09; as empty

Answer (score 0):

I can do it with c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>" +
                "<nodes xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
                    "<element>Content1</element>" +
                    "<element>Content2</element>" +
                    "<element>Content3</element>" +
                    "<parent>" +
                        "<element>Content4</element>" +
                        "<element>Content5</element>" +
                            "<parent>" +
                                "<element>Content6</element>" +
                                    "<parent>" +
                                        "<element>Content7</element>" +
                                        "<element>Content8</element>" +
                                    "</parent>" +
                                "<element>Content9</element>" +
                            "</parent>" +
                        "<element>Content10</element>" +
                        "<element>Content11</element>" +
                    "</parent>" +
                    "<element>Content12</element>" +
                    "<parent>" +
                        "<element>Content13</element>" +
                        "<element>Content14</element>" +
                    "</parent>" +
                    "<element>Content15</element>" +
                "</nodes>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
            string output = "<pre>\n";

            XElement nodes = doc.Element("nodes");
            int level = 0;
            GetChild(ref output, nodes, level);
            output += "</pre>\n";
        }
        static void GetChild(ref string output, XElement nodes, int level)
        {
            foreach (XElement element in nodes.Elements())
            {
                switch(element.Name.ToString())
                {
                    case "parent" :
                        GetChild(ref output, element, level + 1);
                        break;
                    case "element" :
                        output += new string(' ',4 * level) + element.Value + "\n";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    }



}​
```

Answer (score -1):

Hard to answer precisely with no xslt sample, but here what i can give you as a raw answer :

```
<xsl:template match="element">
   <xsl:variable name="parentsCount" select="ancestor::parent"/>
   ... here what you want to do, and you can use the $parentsCount variable....
</xsl:template>
```